# login in php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to login. I have already created table. The elements for username and password are admin. But I can not connect to my db, it shows only "NOT CONNECTED". Where I went wrong I dunno. Please help!

```
<?php
  $servername ="localhost";
  $username ="root";
  $password ="";
  $dbname ="agrobank";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed!" .$admin->connect_error);
  }

  if (isset($_GET['loginn'])) {
    // print_r("Check");
    // $sql = " SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username ";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    if($conn-> query($sql)===TRUE) {
      echo '<center><h2> You are registered successfully </h2></center>';
      // echo '<center><h2><a href="main.php"> Back to main</a></h2></center>';
    } else {
      echo '<center><h2> NO CONNECTED </h2></center>';
      // header('Location: re.php');
      // echo "<script>alert('The same isbn')</script>";
    }
  }
  $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Is you are getting the message `NO CONNECTED` then the query failed. If the connection was failing you would get the message from this line `die("Connection failed!" .$admin->connect_error);`

Comment: Replace this misleading error with `echo '<center><h2>' . mysqli_error($conn) . '</h2></center>';` and you should get some useful information

Comment: This code is broken in a number of fundamental ways (Don't build SQL queries by appending strings! You'll risk an SQL injection.  Don't store passwords in plain text!  You risk embarrassing and dangerous data leaks) but the most obvious flaw is that you're using the database username and password as the user username and password

Comment: Try to see what went wrong with ```$conn->error``` or ```mysqli_error($conn)```

Comment: In future while testing, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: while checking the execution of sql query you should write :
**if($conn->query($sql))**

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
<?php
    $servername ="localhost";
    $username ="root";
    $password ="";
    $dbname ="agrobank";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed!" .$conn->connect_error);
    }

     if (isset($_GET['loginn'])) {
        // print_r("Check");
    // $sql = " SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username ";

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {

                echo '<center><h2> You are registered successfully </h2></center>';
                // echo '<center><h2><a href="main.php"> Back to main</a></h2></center>';
            }else 
            {
                echo '<center><h2> NO CONNECTED </h2></center>';
                // header('Location: re.php');
                // echo "<script>alert('The same isbn')</script>";
            }
     }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: If you post an answer, try to explain mistakes you fixed, or what you advise to OP.

Comment: i just change  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) to  if($conn->query($sql))

Comment: it only shows nme YOU ARE REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY. If i write wrong password and username, it needs to show me NOT CONNECTED. In any cases it shows YOU ARE REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY

Comment: 1) add this line $result = $conn->query($sql); after sql query
2) replace this linke  if($conn->query($sql) to if ($result->num_rows > 0)